# 404 error received for working url using python urllib2

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, urllib2

I am trying to get the following url: ow dot ly/LApK30cbLKj that is working but I am getting http 404 error:

```
            my_url = 'ow' + '.ly/LApK30cbLKj'     # SO won't accept an ow.ly url
            headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent } 
            request = urllib2.Request(my_url,"", headers)

            response = None
            try: 
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                print '+++HTTPError = ' + str(e.code)
```

Is there something I can do to get this url with a http 200 status as I do when I visit in a browser?

Comment: @HughBothwell yes is is, but SO wouldn't let me post that

Comment: I get HTTP 200 if I use requests instead of urllib2, I don't think if this is helpful to you as for all I know you're using urllib2 for a particular reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me, except you need to add http://

```
my_url = 'http://ow' + '.ly/LApK30cbLKj'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the url's protocol, the thing is that when you visit the url in browser, the default protocol will be HTTP. However, urllib2 doesn't do that for you, you need to add `http://` in the beginning of url, otherwise, the error will be raised:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: ow.ly/LApK30cbLKj
```

Answer (score 0):

As @enjoi mentioned, I used requests:

```
import requests

result = None
            try:
                result = requests.get(agen_cont.source_url)
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
                print '+++timeout exception: ' 
                print e
            except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as e:
                print '+++ too manuy redirects exception: ' 
                print e
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print '+++ request exception: ' 
                print e
            except Exception:
                import traceback
                print '+++generic exception: ' + traceback.format_exc()

            if result:
                final_url = result.url
                print final_url
                response = result.content
```